# Error with Primary Key(auto-increment int) Calling stored procedure in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

// STORED PROCEDURE NAME: insertName, _id is an auto-increment

```
try { 

        $sql = "CALL insertName(:_id, :_name)";
        $res = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $res -> bindValue(":_id","NULL");
        $res -> bindValue(":_name",$name);
        $res->execute(); 
        $res->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
} catch( PDOException $e ) {

        die( "ERROR ..." .$e->getMessage());
}
```

// if i try inserting directly a number all goes OK

```
try {  
        $sql = "CALL insertName(:_id, :_name)";

        $res = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $res -> bindValue(":_id",1);
        $res -> bindValue(":_name",$name);
        $res->execute(); 
        $res->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
} catch( PDOException $e ) {

        die( "ERROR ..." .$e->getMessage());
}
```

// Even if i try this without using the stored procedure goes OK

```
try {  
        $sql = 'INSERT INTO (id,name) VALUES (NULL,"'.$name.'" )';
        $res = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $res->execute(); 
} catch( PDOException $e ) {

        die( "ERROR ..." .$e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: `"NULL"` is a string and not mysql `NULL`

Comment: I tried with NULL without " " and don't give me errors. The problem is that doesn't insert the result into the database. When i use a number at NULL place, it goes to work

Answer (score 0):

insert the name value only, since the id is auto increment, it will take values by itself

Answer (score 0):

You should set variable with `NULL` as string, then pass it to `bindValue`:

```
try { 
        $id = "NULL"
        $sql = "CALL insertName(:_id, :_name)";
        $res = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $res -> bindValue(":_id", $id);
```

And you have to be sure, that you can save NULL as value for that column!

Answer (score 0):

```
//I changed the stored procedure
```

start transaction;

DELIMITER |

CREATE PROCEDURE insertName(_name)

`BEGIN`

`//operations`

```
INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES (NULL,_name);
```

END;

|DELIMITER ;

commit;

```
//and then i call insertName(_name)
```